# Lazy-loading images is not working in iPhone browser

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, lazy-loading

Lazy loading images in the iPhone 8s Plus (iOS 11.4) browser does not work. It does work on iPhone 8 (iOS 12.4), Android and in both safari on the mac and chrome on the mac.

Does not work in safari or chrome app on the iPhone 8s Plus.

What can I do to either make it work on all devices or disable it on certain devices?

Thank you.

Here is my lazy loading code: 
JS:

```
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-image');

const imgOptions = {
    threshold: 0,
    rootMargin: "0px 0px 500px 0px" 
};

const lazyLoad = target => {
  const io = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {

      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        const img = entry.target;
        const src = img.getAttribute('data-lazy');

        img.setAttribute('src', src);
        img.classList.add('fade');

        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });
  }, imgOptions);

  io.observe(target)
};

targets.forEach(lazyLoad);
```

HTML:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.0.118:8006/js/jQuery.js"></script>

<div id='item' class='tall'>
  <img class='gallery-image' data-lazy='images/one.jpg' data-fullsize='images/one.jpg'/>
</div>

<script src="http://192.168.0.118:8006/js/lazy-load.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi @FredrikBurmester , were you able to get it working?

Comment: @Shailesh no i used another JS library.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t identify the reason in the code that you’ve provided directly, but you could use the polyfill that I‘ve developed for this aspect, which works in all those browsers and even also gives you aspects like graceful degradation in case of no-js etc.: https://github.com/mfranzke/loading-attribute-polyfill